# Can Google Assistant SDK be integrated with my own app?

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

I was wondering if it was possible to integrate the Google Assistant SDK into my own Android app?

I would like to use voice transcript from the user in order to perform certain actions in the app.

Comment: Hi David, are you able to achieve this? I am also in search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Google Assistant:

According to the Google Assistant SDK guide [page:](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/develop/grpc/)

> The Google Assistant gRPC API gives you full control over the integration with the Assistant by providing a streaming endpoint. Stream a user audio query to this endpoint to receive a Google Assistant audio response.

That guide page will help you integrate and **use** google assistant in your app - your users say something and receive an audio response from Google Assistant.

---

#### Api.ai:

And if you want [actions](https://api.ai/docs/integrations/actions-on-google), you will need to use [api.ai](https://api.ai/) - which allows you to build apps **for** the Google Assistant.